# grouping by column variables and appending a new variable based on condition

Tags: r, dplyr

Say I have a dataframe-

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| id1 | blue |
| id1 | red |
| id1 | grey |
| id2 | red |
| id3 | red |
| id3 | grey |

I would like this output-

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| id1 | all.mixed |
| id2 | red |
| id3 | red.grey |

I tried this-
`table1 <- mydf %>% group_by(ColA, ColB) %>% count(ColB)`
and came to this-

```
ColA ColB                n
  <chr>   <chr>           <int>
1 id1    blue              1
2 id1    red        1
3 id1   grey             1
4 id2   red       1
5 id3   red     1
6 id3  grey1     1
```

But I am kind of lost after this. I thought of group_by and summing up the rows in the colB, but then if I have a situation such that-

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| id5 | grey |
| id5 | grey |

Then what do i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slightly different approach using `group_by` + `summarise` which uses an indicator to replace the `all.mixed` cases in an additional `mutate` step:

```r
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  group_by(Column.A) |> 
  summarise(all.mixed = all(unique(dat$Column.B) %in% Column.B), 
            Column.B = paste(Column.B, collapse = "."), .groups = "drop") |> 
  mutate(Column.B = if_else(all.mixed, "all.mixed", Column.B)) |> 
  select(-all.mixed)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   Column.A Column.B 
#>   <chr>    <chr>    
#> 1 id1      all.mixed
#> 2 id2      red      
#> 3 id3      red.grey
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- data.frame(
          Column.A = c("id1", "id1", "id1", "id2", "id3", "id3"),
          Column.B = c("blue", "red", "grey", "red", "red", "grey")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear how you are determining the values for column B in the output (e.g. "all.mixed"), but let's assume there is a `calcMagicValue` function. The general flow would be something like this:

```
calcMagicValue <- function(vals){
  
  # psuedo code
  if(all(possibleVals %in% vals)){
    "all.mixed"
  } else if( hasRedAndGrey){
    "red.grey"
  } else if(onlyRed) {
    "red"
  } else {
    #...other conditions...
  }
}

myDf |> 
  group_by(ColA) |> 
  summarize(newColB = calcMagicValue(ColB))
```

After grouping by, summarize will iterate through the unique values in the grouped columns, and pass the matching rows the functions called (in this case `calcMagicValue`). In this case, your result will then have one row for each unique combination/values in the grouped columns(s).